# How to delete saved passwords from the browser, programmatically

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, passwords

Does anyone know how to delete passwords in Firefox, Chrome and IE with C#?
I have tried doing this in a lot of ways but I have not been successful in that I cannot find the place they are stored to delete them.
I looked in http://kyrionhackingtutorials.com/2012/03/all-saved-password-location but i cant seem to find and delete them.

```
public static void deleteHistory(string browser)

    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "explorer":
                RegistryKey r = Registry.CurrentUser;
                try
                {
                    r.DeleteSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no passwords deleted : " + e);
                }
                   string Efilepath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + explorerPath;
                string[] Edirctorys = Directory.GetFiles(Efilepath);
                foreach (string dir in Edirctorys)
                {
                    File.Delete(dir);
                }
                break;
            case "chrome":
                string[] filePaths;
                if (File.Exists(chromePathXP))
                {
                     filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(chromePathXP);
                    foreach (string file in filePaths)
                        File.Delete(file);
                }
                if (File.Exists(chromePathVista))
                {
                    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(chromePathVista);
                    foreach (string file in filePaths)
                        File.Delete(file);
                }
                break;
            case "firefox":


                string displayName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
                string filepath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + firefoxPath+displayName;

                //string[] dirctorys = Directory.GetDirectories(filepath);
            //    foreach (string dir in dirctorys)

                    foreach (string file in firefoxFiles)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(filepath + "\\" + file))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(filepath + file);
                            File.Delete(filepath + "\\" + file);
                        }
                    }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the information on the website you linked is correct. I believe the passwords etc for Firefox moved into the profile folder some time ago....

For Firefox the profile folder is located in

%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default.

%APPDATA% is shorthand for the C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla (Win 7/Vista) 
(or C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Mozilla for Win XP)

key3.db etc should be in there

Can't help you out with the others I'm afraid as I don't use them

Comment: what in the xxxxxx.default folder i need to delete?

Comment: same as on the webpage though on FF16 and 17 I believe they are signons.sqlite, signons2.sqlite etc rather than text files

Comment: Looking at the site you linked to it's roughly right but requires some leg work too. I'd install all the browsers etc on a test machine and then locate the files with wildcards for the extensions.... you could always ignore the extensions in your code too

Comment: Another bit I missed off is that the 8 random digits (xxxxxxxx) are randomly generated. However it always has .default at the end for the users (defined by username) main profile which defeats the idea of the random generator as you can scrape *.default folder to look for the passwords etc

Answer (score -1):

To Clear Username,Password it will be like that in C#

```
            TextBox_UserName.Attributes["AUTOCOMPLETE"] = "off";
            TextBox_NewPassword.Attributes["AUTOCOMPLETE"] = "off";
            TextBox_ConfirmNewPassword.Attributes["AUTOCOMPLETE"] = "off";
```

Comment: This doesn't delete saved passwords on the browser, it just prevents autocompletion in the the first place.